# Dozer: map single field to Set

Tags: java, dozer

How do you map a single field into a `Set` in Dozer?

I have a class like:

```
class FooDTO {
    private IdDto bar;
    private IdDto baz;
}

class FooDomainObject {
    private List<Id> ids;
}
```

I'd like to map `bar` and `baz` into the `ids` list, but I can't get it to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on the Dozer support list:

```
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/forums/forum/452530/topic/1557144
```

Basically, you use this syntax:

```
       <field>
            <a>bar</a>
            <b>ids[0]</b>
            <b-hint>org.foo.Id</b-hint>
        </field>
       <field>
            <a>baz</a>
            <b>ids[1]</b>
            <b-hint>org.foo.Id</b-hint>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to do sth. like this :

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>SourceObject</class-a> 
    <class-b>blaObject</class-b> 
    <field>
        <a>sourceObjectSubObject[standardID].fielda</a>
        <b>blaDestField</b> 
    </field> 
</mapping>
```

Where the `standardID` is a field in the `sourceObject`,
and the `sourceObjectSubObject` is a `List<sourceObjectSubObject>`.