# Dozer: Map single field into a List

Tags: java, dozer

How do you map a single field into a `List` / `Collection` in Dozer?

```
class SrcFoo {
    private String id;
    private List<SrcBar> bars;
}

class SrcBar {
    private String name;
}
```

Here are my destination objects:

```
class DestFoo {
    private List<DestBar> destBars;
}

class DestBar {
    private String fooId; // Populated by SrcFoo.id
    private String barName;
}
```

I want all `DestBar.fooId` (entire list of DestBars) to be populated with `SrcFoo.id`

This question is similar to this one posted here, expect I want to map my single field to every item in the list. [Dozer: map single field to Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801593/dozer-map-single-field-to-set)

I tried the following, but it only populated `DestBar.fooId` for the first item in the list.

```
<mapping> 
     <class-a>SrcFoo</class-a> 
     <class-b>DestFoo</class-b> 
     <field>
         <a>bars</a>
         <b>destBars</b>
     </field> 
     <field>
         <a>id</a>
         <b>destBars.fooId</b> <!-- same affect as destBars[0].fooId ? -->
     </field> 
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dozer does not support that type of mapping. In order to do that type of mapping, you would have to know the indexes on your Collection (static mapping). 
This a Job for a custom converter, Create a converter of String to List (of DestBar) like this:

```
public class YourConverter extends DozerConverter<String, List>
```

Implement the mapping logic in your converter (Just set the String Id where required) and configure your dozer file like this:

```
<mapping> 
     <class-a>SrcFoo</class-a> 
     <class-b>DestFoo</class-b> 
     ...
     <field custom-converter="yourpackage.YourConverter">
         <a>id</a>
         <b>destBars</b>
     </field> 
</mapping>
```